# Uninstalling and upgrading Ruby on a Mac without using RVM

Tags: ruby, uninstallation

I recently decided to uninstall RVM from my system.  Some of the arguments made at [this page](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#readme) convinced me:

Actually, what I decided, however, is that I don't want to worry about multiple versions of Ruby at all.  I just want to use version 1.9.2-p290 and not worry about anything else. When I run `ruby --version` on my Mac, though, it tells me I have version 1.8.7.  I have looked around for how to simply uninstall this Ruby from my Mac, but I haven't found anything, weirdly.  It seems that the only people who ever want to uninstall Ruby run linux and everyone using a Mac recommends RVM.

How do I uninstall Ruby 1.8.7 from my Mac?  I'd like to move to version 1.9.2-p290 and I'd like to have only one version on my system.

Comment: The base 1.8.7 Ruby (known as "System" Ruby) on macs is required by the system and cannot be removed, even with sudo. The only option is to replace it with a separate installation and change the PATH as @Winfield says.

Comment: As @t_scho says, do NOT remove 1.8.7. Apple installed it for their purposes. You can use `find /usr -type f -name \*.rb` to get an idea what uses it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Upgrading Ruby on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454792/upgrading-ruby-on-mac-os-x), [How to Upgrade to Ruby 1.9.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546573/how-to-upgrade-to-ruby-1-9-2), and more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easier to install a new version of ruby and just update your path so that all of the binaries reference your new installation.  I do this locally with REE (installed in /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02)

```
export PATH=/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin:$PATH

$> which ruby
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby
```

You don't get the advantage (or complexity) of hot-swapping ruby interpreters on the fly like RVM, but I set this up when I built this dev system and have never had to change it.

**Since ruby comes with OSX, I don't recommend trying to remove it, just work-around the system version.**

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to try and install 1.9.2-p290 from source and then point all my work to that.  Look for another question on here soon regarding why I am having some difficulty installing from source.

Comment: Feel free to contact me at winfield.peterson@gmail.com if you want help getting it setup.  You may be better off using homebrew or macports vs. installing for source.

Answer (score 2):

You should go with [macports](http://www.macports.org/) and install [ruby19](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=ruby19) port:

`sudo port install ruby19 +nosuffix`

The new ruby version will take precedence over the preinstalled one.