# Rails installation emitting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I put this into the terminal:

```
sudo gem install rails -V
```

And I'm getting this error output:

```
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-1.4.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bb-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-1.4.2.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-1.4.3.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-1.4.3.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-1.4.4.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-1.4.4.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-1.4.5.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
```

... at which point it finally says that it cannot install rails.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Problem was that I had Ruby 1.8.7 installed. I just updated to v2.0.0 with the help of [Uninstalling and upgrading Ruby on a Mac without using RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326871/uninstalling-and-upgrading-ruby-on-a-mac-without-using-rvm).